# laravel query php how to get max value within a range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

hello how do i get the max value of scores, where column ID range starts at 3-5
example table 
[image]

I want to get the max value of scores, where column ID ranging from 3-5
, please help,

what I have done so far:

```
$max_scores_table= DB::table('scores_table')
->where('id', '>', 2)
->max('score');
```

another problem is when i have a decimal points in the table
when I used the max() function it gets the ID=5, which has a Score of 4.5, instead of ID=4 with a value of 4.6, tnx in advance

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `whereBetween` hope this works:

```
$max_scores_table= DB::table('scores_table')
    ->select(DB::raw('MAX(score) FROM scores_table as MaxScore'))
    ->whereBetween('id', array(3,5))
    ->where('score', 'MaxScore')
    ->get();
```

OR:

```
$max_scores_table= DB::table('scores_table')
    ->whereBetween('id', array(3,5))
    ->max('score')
    ->get();
```

Comment: tnx it works, but i forget to mention another problem if its apropriate to add here, how can I get the max value where there is a decimal point, sory for adding another question,  i'll just edit my question ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Write query as below:

```
$max_scores_table = DB::table('scores_table')
     ->whereBetween('id',array(3,5))
     ->max('score');
```

**Reference:** [Laravel API](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereBetween)

Answer (score 0):

Use query like this

```
$max_scores_table = DB::table('scores_table')
                    ->whereBetween('id', array(3, 5))->max('score')->get();
```

For your reference just follow [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)