# Getting max and min value in Laravel from MongoDb Database

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to get the maximum and minimum value from the database from a products table. But it is giving unexpected results which is not even logical and correct.
I am not able to understand what's wrong with the query. I am using MongoDb.
I have also checked the link [laravel query php how to get max value within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448857/laravel-query-php-how-to-get-max-value-within-a-range), i think the queries are correct. What may be wrong. The queries are:

```
echo "Max Value ".$max_scores_table = DB::table('products')->where('status', 'enabled')->max('product_data.15');
echo "Min Value ".$min_scores_table= DB::table('products')->where('status', 'enabled')->min('product_data.15');
```

And it is returning me this:

```
Max Value 99
Min Value 100
```

But the "Maximum" query returns "99" and the "Minimum" returns "100" ( Yes this  is what it is giving, i have not typed it wrong) from the database. Even there are less values than 99 and greater value than 100. But it does not return those.

My Collection structure is as:

```
{
  "_id": "574d6814ab8ff4110a75ee58",
  "product_data": {
    "15": "2000",
    "16": "2000",
   },
  "status": "enabled",
}

{
  "_id": "574d6814ab8ff4110a75ee59",
  "product_data": {
    "15": "99",
    "16": "2000",
   },
  "status": "enabled",
}

{
  "_id": "574d6814ab8ff4110a75ee60",
  "product_data": {
    "15": "100",
    "16": "2000",
   },
  "status": "enabled",
}
```

There are also other fields in the collection than these, I've removed them to shorten the length. Can any one help, What's wrong with the query.

Comment: Your entries in the db seem to be of the type string, thats the reason for "99" being the max.

Comment: You need to store your values as type integer, otherwise they will be interpreted as string

Comment: I changed the value from "15": "2000" to "15": 2000 but nothing changed. Also "15": NumberInt(2000), does nothing to the result. Can you tell me the format what to save to check. Thnks

Comment: Have you changed all values to int or just one?

Comment: @KiwiJuicer Firstly I was checking on the same collection. Now I created a new collection and checked it over there with these values. It works. Thanks.